# Add multiple columns and values to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I will ask my question with a small dataframe, but the real one is 1000s of lines.

```
ID  Name     #Required
123 New York  5
234 Boston    6
345 Miami     2
345 Dallas    7
```

I need the to the number of columns equals to the max in the '#Required' column and fill them in like this:

```
ID  Name     #Required J01     J02      J03     J04      J05     J06     J07      
123 New York  5        123W001 123W002  123W003 123W004 123W005  "blank"    "blank"
234 Boston    6        234W001 234W002  234W003 234W005 234W005  234W006 "blank"
345 Miami     2        345W001 345W002  "blank" "blank" "blank"  "blank"   "blank"
399 Dallas    7        399W001 399W002  399W003 399W004 399W005  399W006    399W007
```

The number of values for each row depends on the number in the "#Required" column. with a "W" after "ID" and also I need to know how to handle the values if the number in "#Required" is greater than 10, because then the entry should be 123W010, only 1 leading 0.

```
ID  Name     #Required J01     J02      J03     J04      J05     J06     J07     
123 New York  5        123W001 123W002  123W003 123W004 123W005  "blank"  "blank"
234 Boston    6        234W001 234W002  234W003 234W005 234W005  234W006 "blank"
345 Miami     2        345W001 345W002  "blank" "blank" "blank"  "blank" "blank"
399 Dallas    7        399W001 399W002  399W003 399W004 399W005  399W006   399W007
```

Comment: Interesting problem. the conversion of 10 to `010` and 8 to `008` etc can be done with `format(i, '03d')`, where `i` is the integer. This can be used in parallel with other `pandas` methods to solve your problem. I have added a solution with some explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. Here is a pandas way of doing this. Explanation in the second section -

```py
# Your dummy dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 234, 345, 399],
                   'Name': ['New York', 'Boston', 'Miami', 'Dallas'],
                   '#Required': [5, 6, 2, 7]})

# Creating list of the required values per row
new_lists = df.apply(lambda x: [str(x['ID'])+'W'+format(i, '03d') for i in range(1,x['#Required']+1)], 1)

# Converting the list to individual columns with nan values
new_cols = new_lists.apply(pd.Series)

# Creating column names
col_names = ['J'+format(i, '02d') for i in range(1,len(new_cols.columns)+1)]

# Adding new columns to original dataframe
df[col_names] = new_cols

# Replacing nan values via "blank"
df = df.fillna('"blank"')

df
```

[image]

---

## Explanation

1. The `format(x, '03d')` gives you are 3 length string formed with a digit, so for `1 -> 001` and for `10 -> 010`
2. You can form the required strings for each row using `str(x['ID'])+'W'+format(i, '03d')` where `i` is the range of digits from 1 to the value in the `#Required` column.
3. The `[str(x['ID'])+'W'+format(i, '03d') for i in range(1,x['#Required']+1)]` is a list comprehension that gives you the result as a list. So, if you print the `new_lists`, it will look like this -

```
print(new_lists)

0        [123W001, 123W002, 123W003, 123W004, 123W005]
1    [234W001, 234W002, 234W003, 234W004, 234W005, ...
2                                   [345W001, 345W002]
3    [399W001, 399W002, 399W003, 399W004, 399W005, ...
dtype: object
```

4. Next, with the `.apply(pd.Series)` you get the lists, expanded to individual columns, and the smaller length lists fill up the rest of the columns with `Nan` values. Printing the `new_cols` at this stage results in this -

```
print(new_cols)
         0        1        2        3        4        5        6
0  123W001  123W002  123W003  123W004  123W005      NaN      NaN
1  234W001  234W002  234W003  234W004  234W005  234W006      NaN
2  345W001  345W002      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
3  399W001  399W002  399W003  399W004  399W005  399W006  399W007
```

5. Now to create the column names, we again use just a simple list comprehension, with the range of the number of columns in the `new_cols` and leverage the previously used `format(x, '02d')` but this time for 2 digits.

```
print(col_names)

['J01', 'J02', 'J03', 'J04', 'J05', 'J06', 'J07']
```

6. Finally you add the `new_cols` as new columns to the original dataframe `df` by using `df[col_names] = new_cols`
7. And, last but not the least, you replace the `nan` values with `"blank"` as your question show, using a simple `df.fillna('"blank"')`

---

## Bonus

Here is how the code works if you have double digit integers in #Required column, such as 10 or 12

```
# Sample dataframe with 12 and 10 values in #Required
df = df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 234, 345, 345],
                   'Name': ['New', 'Boston', 'Miami', 'Dallas'],
                   '#Required': [5, 10, 2, 12]})

new_lists = df.apply(lambda x: [str(x['ID'])+'W'+format(i, '03d') for i in range(1,x['#Required']+1)], 1)
new_cols = new_lists.apply(pd.Series)
col_names = ['J'+format(i, '02d') for i in range(1,len(new_cols.columns)+1)]
df[col_names] = new_cols
df = df.fillna('"blank"')
df
```

[image]

Notice that the column names went from `J01 to J12` and the values for the new columns for the rows with `#Required` values like 10 or 12 look like `234W010` or `399W012`.

---

## EDIT

For 1-2 digit ids you can modify the code with the same format logic as before.

```
# Sample dataframe 2 digit IDs
df = df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 34, 345, 99],
                   'Name': ['New York', 'Boston', 'Miami', 'Dallas'],
                   '#Required': [5, 3, 2, 4]})

new_lists = df.apply(lambda x: [format(x['ID'], '03d')+'W'+format(i, '03d') for i in range(1,x['#Required']+1)], 1)
new_cols = new_lists.apply(pd.Series)
col_names = ['J'+format(i, '02d') for i in range(1,len(new_cols.columns)+1)]
df[col_names] = new_cols
df = df.fillna('"blank"')
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Akshay, the answer is perfect. However, I do have a question, what if I have an ID that's only 2 digits, I still need to fill in the column with a leading 0, how would I do that?

Comment: Glad to help. do mark the answer if it worked for you. thanks!. Also, for your additional question, could you elaborate with an example? I can see what I can do to solve it.

Comment: This is my first time here, I am trying to figure out where to mark the answer, I will do it as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: ID   Name       #Required  J01       J02       J03
23   New York      3       023W001  023W002   023W003
                           (0+ID+W+001)

Comment: Do you understand my question, if the ID for New York for example is just 23 instead of 123, I need the value in the column to be 023Wxxx

Comment: I have added an EDIT section to my code with solution to that. All you need is `format(x['ID'], '03d')` instead of the `str(x['ID'])` that I was using before. Do see if that works and feel free to upvote if it helps!

Comment: It works beautifully. Also, I have changed "blank" to "", because I needed an actual blank. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it

Comment: Glad to help. do understand how the `format()` method works so you can modify the answer to your needs.

Comment: Interesting, good work

Comment: I do understand the format concept, I just didn't know the syntax and could not get it to work, now I do though

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed code**

```py
import pandas as pd

# Your dummy dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 234, 345, 399],
                   'Name': ['New York', 'Boston', 'Miami', 'Dallas'],
                   '#Required': [5, 6, 2, 7]})

m = max(df['#Required']) # Maximum number in '#Required'
lm = len(str(m)) # length of the maximum number in '#Required'

how_to_fill = {'J%s'%str(n).zfill(1+lm):['%sW%s'%(i,str(n).zfill(2+lm)) if n <= r else 'Blank' for i,r in zip(df['ID'], df['#Required'])] for n in range(1, m+1)}

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(how_to_fill)).set_index('ID')

print(df)
```

**Result :**

```
         Name  Required      J01      J02  ...      J04      J05      J06      J07
ID                                          ...                                    
123  New York          5  123W001  123W002  ...  123W004  123W005    Blank    Blank
234    Boston          6  234W001  234W002  ...  234W004  234W005  234W006    Blank
345     Miami          2  345W001  345W002  ...    Blank    Blank    Blank    Blank
399    Dallas          7  399W001  399W002  ...  399W004  399W005  399W006  399W007
```

**Note :**

I suggest you the use of `np.nan` with `import numpy as np` instead of "Blank"